# Unknown gap between items

Tags: html, css

I am new to web dev and currently studying on The Odin Project.
I got a problem that there seem a small gap (I'm not sure) between the **header** and **text**. F12 shows no properties that contribute to the gap.

Here is a screenshot of what's happening:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr3OA.png)

And here are the codes:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #aaa;
    color: #333;
    /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
    background: white;
    width: 480px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
}

.icon {
    color: royalblue;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: lavender;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header{
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.text{

}

.close-button {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 0;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
    background: royalblue;
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    color: white;
}

button.cancel {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="icon">!</div>
  <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?
          <button class="close-button">✖</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
      <button class="continue">Continue</button>
      <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your assistance.

I tried setting margin:0 but the gap is still there. F12 also show nothing.

Comment: There is no gap bro this is normal

Comment: it is a normal text gaps, because many symbols can be written lower than baseline. if you want letters to touch each other you can try to reduce the line height

Comment: All fonts will have different heights. There are solutions to rig it, but I only recommend those when the height is too much. The height that you are seeing is normal and not excessive

Comment: I see no gap. Are you talking about the gap between "Are you sure..." text and the "X" icon?